# BufferedImage.getRGB method not consistent - Java AWT

Tags: java, graphics, applet, awt

I have am writing a small game using Applet. I want to be able to check the color of a pixel on the screen. However, when I use .getRGB() on my buffered image in my game loop (a while loop that executes over and over), it gives me inconsistent values even if the pixel color never actually changes!

For example, if I fill the image with green color and I call .getRGB() on a pixel in the middle of the screen sometimes it gives me 0xFF00FF00 (green) as the color, other times it gives me 0xFF000000 (black) even if the color always stays green!

Any help?

Here's the relevant code if that helps, I've minimized it just to focus on the problem:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class t extends Applet implements Runnable {
    Graphics2D      bufferG;
    BufferedImage   bufferI;
    final int       WIDTH   = 500, HEIGHT = 500;
    public void init() {
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        bufferI = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        bufferG = bufferI.createGraphics();
        (new Thread(this)).start();
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            if (bufferI.getRGB(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)==0xFF000000) System.out.println("BLACK");
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        bufferG.setColor(Color.green);
        bufferG.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.drawImage(bufferI, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a kind of guess what my code is doing sort of question which makes me think that you posted it in the wrong forum. Try either posting code and offering a detailed description of the problem and your debug attempts, or try the clairvoyants forum down the hall -- whichever gives you better luck!

Comment: @Hovercraft SSCCE posted as edit (& answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are dealing with buffers.  This paints the image green & produces no output on the command line (reporting the color as black).

```
// <applet code='t' width=400 height=200></applet>
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class t extends Applet implements Runnable {

    BufferedImage   bufferI;
    final int       WIDTH   = 500, HEIGHT = 500;
    public void init() {
        bufferI = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bufferI.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        g.dispose();
        (new Thread(this)).start();
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            if (bufferI.getRGB(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)==0xFF000000) System.out.println("BLACK");
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(bufferI, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

### Notes

#### To compile & run

```
prompt> javac t.java
prompt> appletviewer t.java  // yes that file extension is correct.
```

#### Size

The size of an applet is set in the HTML that loads it, it should not attempt to set its own size.

Comment: I use buffers for double-buffering, because otherwise when you have animation the image flickers like crazy. I'm not sure if the way I'm doing it is most optimal, but that's the way I learned to do it. Thank you for the input!

My hunch is that the while loop calls getRGB on the buffered Image before it's fully drawn - and that's where the color black comes from, since those pixels haven't been filled in yet. I'm trying to find a way to solve this, either by somehow ensuring that the image is completely drawn or by retrieving the actual image object displayed on the screen.

Comment: *"I use buffers for double-buffering"*  Note that Swing (starting with a `JApplet` for example) has double buffering by default.  OTOH I've never seen any flicker when painting a single image directly to the graphics object within paint, using either Swing *or* AWT.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a good time for me to move on from awt to Swing. >_< And I think you only get flicker when you try to animate something, like get a circle to move across the screen.

Comment: *"only get flicker when you try to animate something, like get a circle to move across the screen."*  Yes, I was referring to  animations, I've done a few (dozen) of them - helped people with hundreds.  You can see some samples of my animations in the 'music videos' & 'StarZoom/Wiggly Worms previews' at [my Tube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/DrewTubeish/videos).

Comment: Thanks for your help again. Obviously I still have much to learn, but the method I use to animate an object in AWT is to update its position in the while loop and have a repaint call for every iteration of that loop. That causes flickering if I don't use buffers.